# Rename Term store (root) with powershell - managed metadata service

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata, term-store

Is there a way to rename Term store "root" node?  (yellow in the picture below)

[image]

I've tried

```
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $gurl
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service Application"]
$termStore.Name = "Managed Metadata Service"
```

without luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot edit the Name directly, because the Name of the TermStore is simply the name of the *MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy*.

So what you have to do is to rename that one instead. In your example, you have to get the *SPMetadataServiceApplication* first, find the right proxy and rename it. This should look like this, assumed that your SPMetadataServiceApplication is named "Managed Metadata Service Application"

```
$metadataApplication = Get-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity "Managed Metadata Service Application"
foreach($proxy in $metadataApplication.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup.Proxies)
{
    if($proxy.Name -like "*Managed Metadata Service Application*")
    {
        $proxy.Name = "Managed Metadata Service"
        $proxy.Update()
    }
}
```

or short version

```
$metadataApplication = Get-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity "Managed Metadata Service Application"
$proxy = $metadataApplication.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup.Proxies | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Managed Metadata Service Application*" } 
$proxy.Name = "Managed Metadata Service"; 
$proxy.Update();
```